# PHP System call with JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, xmlhttprequest, system-calls

This is my Javascript:

```
var url = "load.php?x="+x;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
```

where x is a defined variable.

This is my PHP:

```
$var = $_GET['x'];
echo shell_exec('./test2/test2 $var');
```

Where test2 is a folder with an executable file and $var is a parameter. This works when my second statement is

```
echo shell_exec('./test2/test2 param');
```

This shows up in my error log:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_errorstd::logic_error'
 what():    what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not validbasic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You are using single quotes... Try changing to `'./test2/test2' . $var` or `"./test2/test2 $var"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is because you're trying to have a variable interpolated in a string that is defined using single quotes.  Use double quotes instead.  Relevant quote from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

```
echo shell_exec("./test2/test2 $var");
```

Comment: That was synced.. 2s diff xD (from my comment)

Comment: Haha yeah I saw your comment right after I posted.  If this is right, great minds think alike.  If not, we'll hang our heads in shame.